# Valor fijo en un campo tipo text PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo un formulario donde en uno de los campos pido el DNI de una persona. Mi duda es, como puedo hacer que en el input text se mantenga una letra que es necesaria para mi registro del campo del DNI? me explico, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<div class="form-group" style="padding: 20px">

       <select name="c" id="c" onchange="if(this.value!='-') cedula.value=this.value;">
      <option value="-" selected="selected">Elige</option>
      <option value="V"> V </option>
      <option value="E"> E </option>
    </select>




      <label for="nombres" class="col-md-3 control-label">Cedula:<span class="asterisco">*</span>  </label>
        <div class="col-md-8">

  <input type="text" id="ced1" name="cedula" value="<?php if(isset($cedula)) echo $cedula; ?>" /> 


        </div>
     </div>
```

Al seleccionar una opcion del comboBox (V, E..) se llena la caja de texto con esa letra, pero esa letra se puede borrar facilmente al darle a la tecla del teclado de la pc, yo quisiera que no se pudiese eliminar pero no veo la forma.

Intente aplicando mascaras a la caja de texto de la siguiente manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function($){
            $("#numero1").mask("9,99", {

                // Generamos un evento en el momento que se rellena
                completed:function(){
                    $("#numero1").addClass("ok")
                }
            });

            // Definimos las mascaras para cada input
           // $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
            $("#movil").mask("(9999)-999-99-99");
           // $("#letras").mask("aaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            $("#ced1").mask("V-9999999");
             $("#ced2").mask("E-");
              $("#ced3").mask("J-");
           // $("#comodines").mask("?");
           $("#letras1").mask('aaaaaaaaaaaaaa');
        });   </script>
```

pero no me sirve puesto que es una sola caja de texto y si le aplico una sola mascara para una sola letra (La V por ejemplo) no me da para colocar la E... si pudiesen ayudarme se los agradeceria.

Las letras significan la nacionalidad de la persona que se registra, en este caso V- es para venezonalo, y E- para el que es extranjero.

Comment: Es importante que digas, para una posible respuesta, si dicha letra iría siempre en una parte fija del input. Por ejemplo, si va siempre al principio, al final, en medio en una posición X o si puede ir en cualquier posición.

Comment: Hola, en este caso va al inicio siempre, en el siguiente formato por ejemplo V-20.000.000, o sino E-500.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si va siempre en la misma posición, no veo por qué quieres complicarte mezclando el contenido del input con la letra. Puedes hacerlo así:

Pones un select con las letras posibles, y al lado tu input normal, que acepte los otros valores del DNI. Luego puedes obtener el DNI combinando ambos valores.

Creo que es una manera elegante y puedes controlar más fácilmente el contenido de números del DNI etc.

Si quieres, mediante CSS puedes tener dos elementos distintos y hacer que aparezcan como si están juntos :) Como podrás ver, es mucho más cómodo y sencillo manejarlos como elementos separados que puedes combinar según tu necesidad.

He ligado la recogida del valor al evento `onclick` de un botón, pero lo puedes ligar al evento `onchange` del select o a cualquier otro...

Como te has planteado la solución es posible, pero tendrías que pasar por CSS, agregar y quitar las letras del input cada vez que ocurra un `onchange` en el select, etc. Y serían siempre dos elementos distintos, ya que la letra tendría que estar guardada en un div, un span u otro elemento el cual pondrías *como* al lado del input por CSS.

Creo que no hay necesidad. Observa cómo funciona el fragmento de código con la solución que propongo:

```js
$('#btnEnviar').click(function() {
  laLetra = $('#letra').val();
  elNumero = $('#numero').val();
  elDni = laLetra + elNumero;
  alert(elDni);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="letra">
      <option value="V-">V-</option>
      <option value="E-">E-</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="numero" size="15" />
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Hola, muy interesante tu solucion, me ha funcionado pero a medias, puedo agregar el DNI bien, la alerta incluso me muestra el DNI con el formato V-20.000.000, pero al ver en la base de datos para ver como se ha guardado, solamente se guarda el numero 20.000.000 y no se guarda la letra V- o E-, que podria pasar en este caso? gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @rodrigo2324 ese sería ya un problema de la base de datos o del código posterior. No te puedo decir con certeza, pero puede ser que los valores que admitas en la columna `dni` de la bd no admitan letras, o que estén limitados en su espacio, o que el valor sea limpiado de letras en algún lugar antes de insertarlo, etc. Para determinar debes revisar el valor que envías, cómo es manejado ese valor antes de insertarlo en la bd y si la columna de la bd donde lo insertas no tiene restricciones...

Comment: O quizá, como yo a la parte numérica le he dado el id: `id="dni"`  a lo mejor estás recogiendo solamente eso. Como muestra el código de Ajax, tienes que combinar el valor del input cuyo id es `dni` con el valor del select cuyo id es `letra`. Esos ids los puedes cambiar por otros si lo prefieres, claro está.

Comment: Bueno, en este caso lo tengo como varchar(15), y funcionaba con la máscara ced1 que puse en la consulta sin problemas y se guardaba en la BD por ejemplo V-23.897.333 y no generaba error. Cuando hago mi insert, lo hago normal también, nada fuera de lo común, pero hago el INSERT en la parte del DNI a lo que yo ingresé en campo DNI , y como la letra V- y E- ahora están en el combo, creo que ese es el problema. Chequere bien y cualquier cosa comentaré. Gracias nuevamente

Comment: Comentar que, por lo general, no es buena práctica guardar contenido formateado o con máscara en la bd. Lo que se suele hacer es darle formato al presentar los datos. Es como los campos del tipo fecha, que no se guardan formateados. Yendo más lejos, incluso las letras `V` o `E` estarían de más en el sentido de que, usando el país de nacimiento en cualquier consulta, le pondrías la letra correspondiente en forma programática. Es solo un comentario... no quiero liarte más, sino para que lo tomes en cuenta por si quieres optimizar más adelante tu bd :)

Comment: Creo que el problema era que estabas tomando solamente la parte del input, cuyo id era `dni`.  He actualizado el código, dando al select el id `letra` y al input `numero`. El dni lo obtendrás combinando los valores de los elementos `letra + numero` y es ese valor el que debe insertarse en la bd. El dar al input el id `dni` se prestaba a confusión.

Comment: Listo, ya pude lograr que se guardara en mi BD el DNI con la letra como lo necesitaba. Complete tu codigo con otro script donde al presionar el boton registrar, se ejecutara la union de los dos campos de la siguiente manera: 

<script type="text/javascript">

function procesar() {

    laLetra=document.getElementById('letra').value;
    cedula=document.getElementById('dni1').value;

    dnifinal=laLetra+dni;

    document.getElementById('dnifinal').value=dnifinal;

    document.forms.registro.submit();

}

</script>

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @rodrigo2324. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario que te compliques, agrega esa letra a un lado de donde necesitas ingresar el texto.

[LETRA][INPUT TEXTO]

Ya solo con el JavaScript tienes que "actualizar" la letra según tu conveniencia.
Puedes usar un:

```
<span id="letra"></span>
```

Y manipularlo desde ahí.

Answer (score 0):

¿Que tal así?

```js
function evaluarContenido(cadenaIngresada){
  var evaluarCadena = cadenaIngresada.split("");
  if(evaluarCadena[0] != '-'){
    $("#DNI").val("-"+cadenaIngresada);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="DNI" value="" onchange="evaluarContenido(this.value)">
```

Claro que esto es solo un ejemplo y puedes modificarlo a tu necesidad.

Answer (score 0):

No crees que lo podrias realizar con la propiedad readonly = "readonly"? o tienes que colocar la letra en el input y poder editar dicho input?

Comment: tengo que colocar la letra en el input y que no se deje eliminar esa letra y permita que yo coloque lo que desee luego